# How to filter Array of Strings by Array of Strings allowing partial matches

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I have strings in an array and need to remove entries that contain strings. But also removing partial matches.

```
var rawData = ["foo", "bar", "foobar", "barbaz", "boo" ]
var unwantedData = ["foo","baz"]
var cleanData = filter(rawData,unwantedData)
console.log(cleanData)
>>>["bar","boo"]
```

My current solution is as follows:

```
function filter(data,filterArray){
  return data.filter(rawEntry => {
    var t = true; // set to false if index is found
    filterArray.forEach(unwantedStr => { t = t && ~rawEntry.indexOf(unwantedStr) ? false : t });
    return t; //decides if entry gets removed by filter
  });
}
```

But i feel like there might be a nicer way to do it. This is probably computationally not the most efficient way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `.filter()` using `.every()` and `.includes()` methods.

```js
let rawData      = ["foo", "bar", "foobar", "barbaz", "boo"],    
    unwantedData = ["foo", "baz"];

let filterData = (a1, a2) => a1.filter(s => a2.every(v => !s.includes(v)));

console.log(filterData(rawData, unwantedData));
```

Comment: fantastic. somehow missed every. also didn't know you could use includes on strings 2 things learned!

Answer (score 4):

Beside the use of [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), you could do the same by inversing the logic and use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
var rawData = ["foo", "bar", "foobar", "barbaz", "boo"],
    unwantedData = ["foo", "baz"],
    result = rawData.filter(s => !unwantedData.some(t => s.includes(t)));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: In fact, I would recommend *this* solution over the `every` one. When you use `Array#every`, it must look at every element before returning. If you use `Array#some`, it will stop after the very first match, making it oh-so-slightly more efficient of an approach.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk, every has a short cut as well. it ios just inversed. the count if iteration is the same for both.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var rawData = ["foo", "bar", "foobar", "barbaz", "boo" ]
var unwantedData = ["foo","baz"]
var cleanData = rawData.filter((item)=> !unwantedData.includes(item))
console.log(cleanData)
```

Comment: _"But also removing partial matches."_

Comment: @Andy I think it is removing only 'foo'  that is exact match.

Comment: That's not what the OP wants.

Comment: @andy Thanks,  I miss understood  the question.